# How to identify certain words in string and return results ? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform

I am trying return back results such as information about it after identifying certain words from google cloud API. I'm just doing a hard coded results return to the app.

For example, using google cloud text api, the app will return the string of the text on the boxes of Panadol. Within the string, they will identify the word "panadol" and display the results such as description back.

This is the google cloud API tutorial i got from : 
https://www.sitepoint.com/image-recognition-with-the-google-vision-api-and-ionic/

index.html:

This where the returns will be displayed :

listCtrl.image_description is the string from Google Cloud Api
listCtrl.identify_result is description after identifying

```
<h3 class="text-center" ng-show="listCtrl.image_description"> {{ listCtrl.image_description }}</h3>
<h3 class="text-center" ng-show="listCtrl.identify_result"> {{ listCtrl.product_result }}</h3>
```

homecontroller.js :

res.responses[0][key][0].description is the results returned from API

```
 var key = me.detection_types[me.detection_type] + 'Annotations';
 me.image_description = res.responses[0][key][0].description;
```

This is code i used for identifying but it's not working

```
function contains(str,text) {
   return str.indexOf(text) >= 0 ;  
   }
    if (contains(res.responses[0][key][0].description,'panadol')){
    me.product_word = 'Panadol is a drug';
    }
```

App.js

```
nameApp.factory('Authorization', function() {

authorization = {};
authorization.image_description = '';
authorization.product_result = '';

return authorization;
});

nameApp.controller('listCtrl', function($scope,  Authorization) {
$scope.test = Authorization;  
});
```

Any help with making a function will be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Current error : res is not defined

Comment: could you please paste "result.response" response here

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved.

It was solved by shifting this code within the controller just below the response. Thank all for helping :)

```
 function contains(str,text) {
 return str.indexOf(text) >= 0 ;  
 }
if (contains(me.image_description,'panadol')){
me.product_result = 'test';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your contains function.

Try this :

```
function contains(str,text) {
  return str.indexOf(text) >= 0;  
}
```

Comment: Made changes. Still not working. " res is not defined"

Comment: You get this error because you haven't defined variable `res`. I cannot help without full code. Does it come from `product_result ` ? In that case try `var res = JSON.parse(product_result)` or `var res = product_result`